# Unknown Text Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How come when I do a console.log on elements that I append to a parent div come out with a bunch of carriage return nodes. Is there a way to remove this because when I try to add some css to these they break the application.

Here is my setup. I'm using underscore template to create my html. The tmpl is all working fine.

```
    var tmpl = $( template({items : list}) );

    var items = $(_.filter(tmpl, function(item){ 
        return ! $item.hasClass('pin'); 
    }));

    var domItems = items.appendTo($('.container'));
```

Here is the log

```
domItems = 

[<TextNode textContent="\n          \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, <TextNode textContent="\n           \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item, <TextNode textContent="\n         \n              ">, div.item]
```

I just want it to be returning the div.item element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers consider empty spaces as a text node. To filter them, just exclude all `nodeType`s which are equal to `3` ([`Node.TEXT_NODE == 3`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType)):

```
var items = $(_.filter(tmpl, function(item){ 
    return ! $item.hasClass('pin') && this.nodeType !== 3;
}));
```